# Load more WordPress posts on (infinite) scroll with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm currently loading more posts via AJAX when the user clicks on a 'load more' button. The code I'm using is based on this tutorial:

http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/

My aim is to modify that code so that more posts are loaded when a user **scrolls** to the bottom of the page. I've tried replacing

```
$('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').click(function() {

});
```

with this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){

    }
});
```

When doing that, new posts are loaded successfully but when the user scrolls to the bottom of the browser window a second time, the next set of posts are not loaded into the page.

Using the button click approach, a new 'load more' button is added to the page so the next set of posts are loaded if a user clicks again. How can I get my scroll approach to load the next set of posts when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page again?

Comment: i did samething and made tutorial of it :http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/12/infinite-scroll-paging-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html

Comment: I'm worried about the `==` you're using for these types of calculations. I feel like `>=` would be safer. Also, I would suggest you load more posts when the user *approaches* the bottom of the page, instead of when the user *reaches* the bottom of the page. This is standard for most infinite scrolling websites, and allows the post to already be loaded by the time the user wants to see them.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad thanks for the tutorial, I'll take a look

Comment: @Zhihao thanks. I was thinking the same thing regarding 'approaching the bottom of the page' - perhaps I'll change it to ~100px from the bottom. Regarding my use of `==`, what was your concern about?

Comment: @henrywright The scroll event doesn't trigger on every 1px change in the scroll position, but rather on more of an interval of time. That means that when scrolling from position "0" to "100", certain values will be skipped, and more values will be skipped the faster you scroll. For example, event 1 might put you at "0", then event 2 might put you at "10", then event 3 at "50", as you accelerate scroll speed. This means using `==` will not work if there is at all a chance that the numbers are not exact, or that an event is not fired when your two numbers are equal (which there is).

Comment: @henrywright As a side note, you should also be using `===` for comparisons in JavaScript in general. `==` is used for implicit equality, and should only be used if you *really* know what you're doing (and even then it's risky). Basically, `==` can give unexpected results. [Here's a table with more details on `==` comparison](http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/collective/JavaScript-Equality-Table.jpg).

Comment: @Zhihao thanks for the heads up about `===` and `==`. I'll keep that in mind for future.

Answer (score 0):

In your test, instead of using an exact equality :

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
    ...
}
```

try using a threshold, e.g. :

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it and although it loads more when I scroll to the bottom again _slowly_, if I scroll _fast_ it doesn't load the next set of posts. Quite odd! Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: @henrywright Scrolling slowly means more events are fired, which covers more "scroll positions". This gives a higher chance that an event is fired when your condition is met, which I think is the reason why scrolling slowly gives better results. I've explained this in more detail in a comment to your original question. I would recommend using a larger "scroll range" for better results.

Comment: @Zhihao thanks for the explanation, I think the scroll range is the issue I'm having. How would I implement a larger 'scroll range'?

Comment: @henrywright The `10` in LeGEC's answer is basically your range in pixels. Try increasing that to a larger number.

Comment: @Zhihao I just tried 200 but got the same result when scrolling fast. Actually the higher the number I use results in less chance of the second set of posts loading. A lower number like 10 results in the second set of posts loading 9 times out of 10 when I scroll fast. Scrolling slow ensures the second set of posts are loaded regardless of the number I use

Comment: @henrywright That's strange. Would it be possible for you to set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the issue (maybe have it log something instead of making an async request)?

Comment: @Zhihao interestingly `if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height())` (note no minus figure at all) works every time. The only caveat is the user must scroll the entire page. But at least the loading of more posts is always guarunteed to work.

Comment: Oops, scrap that - just tried scrolling again (_fast_) with no minus figure and more posts didn't load.

Comment: OK, I seem to be able to get more posts to load every time using `if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {` - However, there is one scenario when more posts aren't loaded: If the user scrolls half way down the page then hits F5 - waits for the page to load - then scrolls to the bottom of the page. Why would the page refresh stop things from working?

Comment: @henrywright I don't know why that might happen. Did you try debugging it by checking to see if your event handler is still added after refresh? What about checking the actual values of `scrollTop()` and `<$el>.height()`? Can you reproduce the previous issue in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that I can take a look at it as well?

Comment: Humm, I just looked at the source (was trying to create a jsFiddle) and found something strange. Aside from loading more posts, I'm also adding an element to the page - it's a simple placeholder div which says the 2nd round of posts has been added etc. The strange thing is the placeholder div is not removed from the page source when I have scrolled half way down the page and hit F5. That's puzzling because surely F5 should reset the DOM? If I scroll to the top and hit F5 then the DOM is reset (the placeholder is removed as expected)

Answer (score 0):

hey sorry about my english 
try this

```
 $(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
    {
        $('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').trigger('click');
    }});
```

put it above

```
$('#pbd-alp-load-posts a').click(function()
```

that code force button #pbd-alp-load-posts a when scroll right over the end to be clicked 
it's work fine